# Mac Text Editor that Support SSH Keys

Tags: macos, text-editor, ssh-keys

I have a workmate who only uses a Mac.  Being unfamiliar with Mac text editors, I'm wondering if anyone can recommend one that will allow SFTP access using ssh keys (not just passwords).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They would probably use the included OpenSSH libraries.  So you would just need to add the public/private keys in ~/.ssh/

I personally use rsync to synchronize the working set and the remote directory.  Write a small batch file, double click and it synchronizes within a few milliseconds.  If you don't need concurrent editing then this will probably be the more sane solution as you don't need to worry about slow filesystem abstraction layers.  MacFuse is great in theory, but I have had it lock up finder a bit too often for my liking.

Comment: Turns out, this is the correct answer.  I didn't expect the text editor to try the key, on a PC you have to specify it first.  In the mac, I created a key (ssh-keygen), then added that to the file server.  Thanks envalid!

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend checking out [MacFUSE](https://code.google.com/archive/p/macfuse) and [MacFusion](http://macfusionapp.org/) which will allow your workmate to mount ssh shares as native partitions, allowing them to use whatever editor they wish.

[image: MacFUSE]
<sub>(source: [googlecode.com](http://macfuse.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/core/packaging/images/MacFUSE_Banner.png))</sub>

Comment: I've done this on Linux, and it's a great facility as you can then use any editor or IDE that you want transparently. Things get kinda wonky when the link goes down, but there are workarounds for that.

Answer (score 1):

.... not sure, but I'd investigate BBEdit

Comment: Yes, I use BBEdit and regularly use SSH access including public key access, which I accomplish in connection with "SSH Agent", a GUI tool for keeping the keys at the ready.

Answer (score 1):

Cyberduck and TextMate integrate very well - Cyberduck lets you use SFTP, and TextMate is one of the best Mac editors around.

Answer (score 0):

Cyberduck has integration support for many editors.
http://cyberduck.ch/

With it you can browse (edit) FTP, SFTP, WebDAV, Cloud Files and Amazon S3.